# Can't use a form's value in a different php file

Tags: php, forms, post

Having issues with using a form's value in a different php file:

my `firstpage.php`

```
<form method="post">
<input type="radio" name="rdbbtn" value="1"> One
<input type="radio" name="rdbbtn" value="2"> Two
</form>
```

my `secondpage.php` is here

```
<?php   
include("firstpage.php");
$result = $_POST['rdbbtn'];
if ($result == "1") {          
    echo 'thirdpage.php';      
}
else {
    echo 'fourthpage.php';
}
?>
```

problem:

> Notice: Undefined index: rdbbtn in

how come I can't use "rdbbtn"? Should I have something like

```
$rdbbtn = $_POST['rdbbtn'];
```

in secondpage.php? Tried this but didn't solve my problem.
firstpage.php and secondpage.php are in the same directory.
Probably it's some pretty obvious thing that I don't see...thanks!

**EDIT: I have accepted pradeep's answer as that helped me the most to figure what the problem should be. would like to say thank you for everybody else showing up here and trying to help!**

Comment: do like this `$result = isset($_POST['rdbbtn']) ?  $_POST['rdbbtn'] : NULL;`

Comment: thank you, great! this approach seems to eliminate the problem and renders "thirdpage.php" (echo needs to be changed to include though). however, it pops up a different problem, namely, no matter what value does the radio button have, it will never render "fourthpage.php". any ideas why?

Comment: Why doesn't `firstpage.php` have an `action` that sends it to second page?

Comment: i think it is not mandatory to have. also, i need to use it in many other classes, so how would you set the action? action="page5.php", "page6.php" and so on? this is not possible.

Comment: You are always on `firstpage.php` aren't you? Nothing in this code does redirects.

Comment: please note that "echo" is changed to "include", as i mentioned it a few comments above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be like this :

Check with `isset` method in

```
<?php   
include("firstpage.php");
$result = isset($_POST['rdbbtn']) ? $_POST['rdbbtn'] : NULL;
if ($result == 1) {          
    echo 'thirdpage.php';      
}
else {
    echo 'fourthpage.php';
}
?>
```

and your form should be like this :

```
<form method="post">
<input type="radio" name="rdbbtn" value="1"> One
<input type="radio" name="rdbbtn" value="2"> Two
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: This will just suppress the notice, not identify the issue of why the value isn't set.

Comment: use `if ($result == 1) {`  instead of `if ($result == "1") {`

Comment: not the perfect solution, but it helped me to get closer how to fix some issues here and there, therefore I'll accept this answer. thank you!

Comment: pleasure is mine , happy coding

Answer (score 1):

When you change current page it reset the value and `$_POST` is empty.

You can try with set **form action** to next page . It will work

```
<form method="post" action="secondpage.php">
    <input type="radio" name="rdbbtn" value="1"> One
    <input type="radio" name="rdbbtn" value="2"> Two
    <input type="submit" name="" value="Next">
</form>
```

> Other wise you can make a `function` in a class and set each page action
>   to this function.

And set your each form data to `session`.

Finally when you change the page you read data form `session`.

```
Class FormAction{
  public function setFormDataToSession(){
     if(isset($_POST['rdbbtn']){
        $_SESSION['rdbbtn'] = $_POST['rdbbtn'];
     }  
   }
}
```

In your page simply get the **session value**.

```
echo $_SESSION['rdbbtn'];
```

Comment: haven't tried this but the thing is the action is not limited to only "seconpage.php". depending on the user's choice, i'll need to use it many different classes. thanks anyway!

Comment: Notice: Use of undefined constant 1- assumed '1' in

Comment: @Riwi I added a alternative idea and edit my answer . Maybe you gets a hints.Thanks

Comment: thank you. interesting solution. still trying to find a less complicated one

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for not being able to comment in this post(less reputations). But seems like you are asking about storing the variables of the session. This way you can use the variables for a whole session. Just start the session by putting `session_start()` in the very beginning of `secondpage.php` file and then you can access the variables at any time during the session by simply calling `$_SESSION['rdbutton`] in any page like fourthpage.php or anything. Just make sure u put the `session_start()` at the top of each page where you want to use the variables. Don't forget the semicolons at the end.   Hope this helps.

Comment: If it helped. Help me out with ur valuable upvote so that I can comment on the posts in future and do not have to write comments as answers. Just 7 reps away from that milestone. 

Comment: :) sure. this is not the issue though as i pointed out. take my upvote as a thank for your helping intention.

Comment: That is so kind of you. By the way, if you are integrating these webpages with login system do make sure that they can not be accessed directly. I mean add some access validation checks in your webpages. And if It's  just a plain website, you are good to go. 

Comment: the purpose is to make the app as vulnerable as possible for educational services. :)